# Unable to change jQuery button submit to drop down select and submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, forms

I have a wp_query where I would like to change the posts per page via a drop-down select box. The code I have has been pieced together from various tutorials and snippets I already have so bear with me...

My basic wp_query is;

```
<?php

$postsperpage = isset($_POST['amt_per'])? $_POST['amt_per']: 10;


        $args = array(
        'post_type'=>'product',
        'posts_per_page' => $postsperpage,
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<ul>';
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();

            echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';

        wp_reset_postdata();

    } else {

    }

?>
```

The tutorial I used had a few buttons where the values were the number of posts per page;

```
    <form method="post">
  <select id="select-box">
    <option class="amt-button" name="amt_per" value="1">1</option>
    <option class="amt-button" name="amt_per" value="2">2</option>
    <option class="amt-button" name="amt_per" value="3">3</option>
    <option class="amt-button" name="amt_per" value="4">4</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

and the jQuery;

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Postsperpage
    $('select').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

---

What I want to do is change the buttons into a drop-down select box like this;

```
<select id="select-box" method="post">
    <option class="amt-button" name="amt_per" value="1">1</option>
    <option class="amt-button" name="amt_per" value="2">2</option>
    <option class="amt-button" name="amt_per" value="3">3</option>
    <option class="amt-button" name="amt_per" value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

The problem I now have is my amended jQuery won't update the query with correct posts per page, this is what I have come up with;

```
$(function() {
  $('#select-box').on('change', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('form')
           .trigger('submit')
  })
})
```

any and all help is appreciated, Thanks!!

***UPDATE***

Thanks to @Krystian Barchański I've updated my dropdown code and wrapped the  in a . This has got the form firing when you select a dropdown value but now the page just reloads with the same posts per page and the dropdown changes back the initial value, I'm assuming this is a jquery issue as when using the buttons everything worked fine?

Comment: no problem, I did sort it hence the deleted question. how do I find it to republish?

Comment: its back now - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52422655/woocommerce-get-available-variations-not-working-with-form-to-populate-wc-get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the select box name  `amt_per`. not for options.

```
 <form method="post" action="">
  <select id="select-box" name="amt_per">
    <option class="amt-button" value="1">1</option>
    <option class="amt-button" value="2">2</option>
    <option class="amt-button" value="3">3</option>
    <option class="amt-button" value="4">4</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: glad to help you

Comment: all working, it was my error for not checking the debug log which sorted me out

Comment: Sorry, I thought I updated this? I've set your answer as the correct one again, let me know if it doesn't show

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap your `<select>` with a `<form>` like this:

```
<form  method="post">
  <select id="select-box">
    <option class="amt-button" name="amt_per" value="1">1</option>
    <option class="amt-button" name="amt_per" value="2">2</option>
    <option class="amt-button" name="amt_per" value="3">3</option>
    <option class="amt-button" name="amt_per" value="4">4</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

In your example you treat `<select>` as it could be submitted and it would send a post request but that can be done only by a form.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select - here you'll find list of available attributes for select there is no `method` nor `url`.

Comment: Thanks, @Krystian Barchański, that's got the form reacting to the select box but now when the page reloads it is still loading the same posts per page and not changing to the value in the select, any ideas?

Comment: he didnt set name for select box.